# how to split the text in scala line by line

Tags: scala

text will be "asd_fgh_jklm"
    output :
    asd
    fgh
    jk
    lm
    if the last word is 4 then 2+2
    if it is 3 then 2+1

Conditions:

Remove all _ characters in string

no.of chars>=4

Print each of 3 charcters in to new line.

If remaining no.of characters < =4

4 - 2+2

3- 2+1

2- 2

1 - 1

then split and print as 2 characters into one line, remaining into next line

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you've attempted so we can better address your learning process.

Comment: Please edit your question to use some kind of code markup, as I can't tell what this question is trying to ask right now. Also as jwvh suggests, please include your current code so we can help you debug why it isn't doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you mean, but maybe this will help you:

```
def magicSplit(str: String, separator: String) =
  str.split(separator).toList match {
    case init :+ last => init ++ last.grouped(2)
  }


val res1 = magicSplit("asd_fgh_jklm", "_")
val res2 = magicSplit("asd_fgh_jk", "_")
val res3 = magicSplit("asd_fgh_j", "_")
val res4 = magicSplit("asd_fgh_jkl", "_")
```

results:

```
res1: List[String] = List(asd, fgh, jk, lm)
res2: List[String] = List(asd, fgh, jk)
res3: List[String] = List(asd, fgh, j)
res4: List[String] = List(asd, fgh, jk, l)
```